# WordPress Custom Plugin cannot set a price on adding a new product

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that extends the popular WooCommerce plugin. It adds a new product type "Metal" and adding custom fields that must be filled in when product type "metal" is selected. Anyway, I'm using the `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook to set the new meta values:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wm_save_fields' );

function wm_save_fields( $id ){
    if(isset($_POST['product-type']) && $_POST['product-type'] == 'metal') {

        $weight = $_POST['_metal_weight'];
        $margin = $_POST['_metal_margin'];

        if(
            !isset($weight) ||
            !isset($margin)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $weight = ($weight == "") ? 0 : sanitize_text_field($_POST['_metal_weight']);
        $margin = ($margin == "") ? 0 : sanitize_text_field($_POST['_metal_margin']);

        $gold_price = get_option('wm_gold_price');

        $price = $weight * $gold_price;
        $margin_price = $price + (($margin / 100) * $price);
        $margin_price = number_format($margin_price, 2);

        update_post_meta( $id, 'wm_weight', $weight );
        update_post_meta( $id, 'wm_margin', $margin );

        if(get_post_meta( $id, '_price' )) {
            update_post_meta( $id, '_price', $margin_price );
        } else {
            add_post_meta( $id, '_price', $margin_price );
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes only when adding a new product. It's not setting the price of the product. It sets an empty string. But on product update it's working perfectly. I tried different approaches of the `update_post_meta` code but nothing worked. Any ideas why is this happening? I'm struggling my head for 2 hours now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this issue could be to use the woocommerce_before_product_object_save action, which is run before the product is saved.

Please try this :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_product_object_save', 'wm_set_price' );

function wm_set_price( $product ){
    if(isset($_POST['product-type']) && $_POST['product-type'] == 'metal') {

        $weight = $_POST['_metal_weight'];
        $margin = $_POST['_metal_margin'];

        if(
            !isset($weight) ||
            !isset($margin)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $weight = ($weight == "") ? 0 : sanitize_text_field($_POST['_metal_weight']);
        $margin = ($margin == "") ? 0 : sanitize_text_field($_POST['_metal_margin']);

        $gold_price = get_option('wm_gold_price');

        $price = $weight * $gold_price;
        $margin_price = $price + (($margin / 100) * $price);
        $margin_price = number_format($margin_price, 2);

        update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'wm_weight', $weight );
        update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'wm_margin', $margin );
        $product->set_price( $margin_price );
    }
}
```